# How can I replace specific part of String with another string in java?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I have been trying to replace specific part of String(array of space characters) with another String.

for Example

```
String string1 = "          ";
String string2 = "hello";
```

I want to replace the first 5 characters in string1 with "hello".
Can anyone help me?
if I print the length of the string1 it should print the original length string1 not the length of string2. 
I don't want trimmed version.

Comment: @user7 they are previous question tags, edited.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of the String class? It has a substring() method. Read the javadoc, and try something.

Comment: @JB Nizet subString did not meet my requirements.

Comment: `String result = string2 + string1.substring(5)` is one of the ways to do what you want. How does it not meet your requirements?

Comment: If your requirements cannot be reached via @JBNizet example, than there is nothing more to do. Your goal is unsolvable except for some Artificial Intelligence. O.K., now let's be serious: can you explain your question - maybe with few others examples of input/desired output?

Comment: I'm sorry. thank you..it works fine. when you say substring() my brain jumps to substring(begin, end) signature.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that works to solve your problem:

```
String one = "    ";
String two = "Hello";
char[] strArray = one.toCharArray();

for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    strArray[x] = two.charAt(x);
    }
one = String.valueOf(strArray);
System.out.print(one);
```

In this example we create an empty String with 5 character spaces like you have in your question. We then create a String that contains the word "Hello". We can create a CharArray[] that will store all of the elements in String one. Since we want to change the first 5 indexes, we will run a loop that iterates 5 times. until the first 5 indexes are changed. On each iteration, we will set the value of that character index in the array to the value of the character index in String two. When the loop is done we set one = to the String value of the Char Array. Here is your output:

```
Hello
```

This solution works along the lines of what you were looking for. For example, lets say you alter the code and String one looks like this:

```
String one = "     theDogCrossedTheRoad";
System.out.println("The length is: " + one.length());
```

The output would be a length of 25 for String one. And then lets test the length of String one after the code executes:

```
System.out.println("The length is: " + one.length());
```

The output would still be 25, so the code doesn't trim the length of your original String. It simply replaces the first 5 characters. And here is your output:

```
The length is: 25
HellotheDogCrossedTheRoad
The length is: 25
```

As you can see the rest of you String is still intact, and the only thing that changed are the first 5 characters. You still have the same character length, so your code will not be Trimmed.

Comment: He/She wants to replace first 5 characters only. Not the whole string or empty string if it exists.
`StringBuilder` is a better choice that provides what he/she wants.

Comment: This example ONLY replaces the first 5 characters, and Hello is 5 characters long. That matches the standards for this example.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo thanks, but this is not useful for me..I want to replace specific part of string..

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo ..It doesn't holding my question anyway resolved with this sinppet String result = string2 + string1.substring(5);

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo in my case string1 contain space characters. your case it's null. please refer my question once again it was edited.

Comment: @kishoref22 Okay. I updated the answer. This answer solves your problem specifically, and you can "accept" the answer with a check mark if it works.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo you are keep missing my question. Here it reads "if I print the length of the string1 it should print the original length of string1 not the length of string2" and In my question length of string1 is greater then string2. If i apply your code, string2 replace the string1 but the length is trimmed. I want the original length of string1. Increse the space characters in your String "one" and apply your code. It doesn't show the original length of "one".

Comment: I didn’t miss it because in this example you’re setting the array to the length of string1. So if you had 40 characters in String 1 for example, this would only alter the first 5 because the length of the array is the length of String1 with all of the values in String1.

Comment: For example if this was your string: String one = "     theDogCrossedTheRoad";     Then your output would be:  HellotheDogCrossedTheRoad . You are altering the first 5 characters in the String and replacing them with Hello from the second string in my example, and keeping the rest of String one intact if that makes since. So the length of String1 remains the same if you use the String.length() method to test. @kishoref22

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo It's working,thank you.I missed it somewhere before.